# Pairwise matching and windowing using Deedle in C#

Tags: c#, dataframe, deedle

Say we want to calculate how the price of some fruits are changing. Starting from a CSV file:

```
Day,Name,Kind,Price
2019-09-04,"apple","red delicious",63.09
2019-09-04,"apple","ginger crisp",52.14
2019-09-04,"orange","navel",41.18
2019-09-03,"apple","red delicious",63.07
2019-09-03,"apple","ginger crisp",52.11
2019-09-03,"orange","navel",41.13
2019-09-02,"apple","red delicious",63.00
2019-09-02,"apple","ginger crisp",52.00
2019-09-02,"orange","navel",41.00
```

with an unknown number of fruits and varieties, we can read the dataframe and build an extra column to use for matching.

```
var fruits_file = Path.Combine(root, "fruits.csv");
Deedle.Frame<int, string> df = Frame.ReadCsv(fruits_file);

Series<int, string> name = df.GetColumn<string>("Name");
Series<int, string> kind = df.GetColumn<string>("Kind");

var namekind = name.ZipInner(kind).Select(t => t.Value.Item1 + t.Value.Item2);
df.AddColumn("NameKind", namekind);
```

but the problem remains. `Deedle.Series.Window()` and `Deedle.Series.Pairwise()` make it possible to perform first-order differences, but not matching based on some string (namekind).

What is the right way to copy over a column `LastPrice` and subsequently calculate the `Change`?

```
Day,Name,Kind,Price,LastPrice,Change
2019-09-04,"apple","red delicious",63.09,63.07,0.02
2019-09-04,"apple","ginger crisp",52.14,52.11,0.03
2019-09-04,"orange","navel",41.18,41.13,0.05
2019-09-03,"apple","red delicious",63.07,63.00,0.07
2019-09-03,"apple","ginger crisp",52.11,52.00,0.11
2019-09-03,"orange","navel",41.13,41.00,0.13
2019-09-02,"apple","red delicious",63.00,,
2019-09-02,"apple","ginger crisp",52.00,,
2019-09-02,"orange","navel",41.00,,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication137
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Fruit fruit = new Fruit(FILENAME);
            Fruit.PrintFruits();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }



    }
    public class Fruit
    {
        public static List<Fruit> fruits { get; set; }
        public DateTime day { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string kind { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }

        public Fruit() { }
        public Fruit(string filename)
        {
            int count = 0;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            string line = "";

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (++count > 1)
                {
                    string[] splitLine = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }).ToArray();

                    Fruit newFruit = new Fruit();
                    if (fruits == null) fruits = new List<Fruit>();
                    fruits.Add(newFruit);

                    newFruit.day = DateTime.Parse(splitLine[0]);
                    newFruit.name = splitLine[1];
                    newFruit.kind = splitLine[2];
                    newFruit.price  = decimal.Parse(splitLine[3]);

                }
            }
            reader.Close();

        }
        public static void PrintFruits()
        {
            var groups = fruits.OrderBy(x => x.day)
                .GroupBy(x => new { name = x.name, kind = x.kind })
                .ToList();

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < group.Count() - 1; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Old Date : '{0}', New Date : '{1}', Name : '{2}', Kind : '{3}', Old Price '{4}', New Price '{5}', Delta Price '{6}'",
                        group.ToList()[i].day.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                        group.ToList()[i + 1].day.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                        group.ToList()[i].name,
                        group.ToList()[i].kind,
                        group.ToList()[i].price.ToString(),
                        group.ToList()[i + 1].price.ToString(),
                        (group.ToList()[i + 1].price - group.ToList()[i].price).ToString()
                        );


                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```